# Why doesn't my code recognize my CloudKit Database?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Scenario: I created a cloud kit container & record in my dashboard. 
          But I can't access it via code.

1) Here's my bundle identifier:
[image]

2) I setup CloudKit in Xcode:
[image]

3) I clicked the 'CloudKit Dashboard' button, went to the corresponding web page and added a record to be fetched:

[image]

The I attempted to extract that data programmatically; and failed:

```
   @IBAction func retrieveRecords(sender: UIButton) {

        let myContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        let publicDatabase = myContainer.publicCloudDatabase

        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let myQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "Students", predicate: predicate)

        publicDatabase.performQuery(myQuery, inZoneWithID: nil) { (record, error) -> Void in
            if (nil != error) {
                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("The Received Record: \(record)")
            }
        }

    }
```

I only get the following error:

> Error: did not find required record type: Students

This should be a simple method with results but apparently, my code doesn't recognize the database to function.   What am I missing?

Comment: In the CloudKit dashboard, click on the top left where is says "MyCloudKit" and make sure you have selected the same container being used by your app.

Comment: Correct Answer!   Thanks!